# How to initialise a global variable in go with a value read from a configuration file at run time

Tags: go, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to initialize a global variable with an interval value which is read from a configuration file at run time.

The configuration file contains set of key-value pairs.As part of init() function, Using yaml parser the values are parsed and stored in a structure.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "time"
        yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func init(){
        PopulateConfig("./test.config")
}

var Conf Config
var Interval = time.Second * Conf.Interval

type Config struct {
        Port     string        `yaml:"port"`
        Interval time.Duration `yaml:"interval"`
}

func PopulateConfig(filePath string) {
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
        err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &Conf)
        if err != nil {
        }
        fmt.Println("CONFIG => ", Conf)
}

func main() {
        // start timer
        fmt.Println("Inside main, Interval = ", Interval)
        purgeTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 10)
        go Handle(purgeTicker)
        time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)

}

func Handle(ticker *time.Ticker) {
        fmt.Println("Inside Handle, Interval = ", Interval)
        for t := range ticker.C {
                fmt.Println("Calling purge timer at ", t)
                //Additional processing
        }
}

===========================

config file:
# cat test.config
port: 1234
interval: 15
```

The config values are populated correctly within the structure.
Expected result is to set the global variable with the value read from file.
But the actual output is 0.
Actual Result:

```
# ./main
CONFIG =>  {1234 15ns}
Inside main, Interval =  0s
Inside Handle, Interval =  0s
```

Comment: The `init()` function prints the `Conf` global variable, which is distinct from the global `Interval` variable. The `init()` function never sets the `Interval` global variable. And inside `main()` and in `Handle()`, you print the `Interval` variable, not the `Interval` field of the `Conf` global variable.

Comment: Package level variable expressions are evaluated first, so `var Interval = time.Second * Conf.Interval` becomes zero, because `Conf.Interval` is zero. `init` is executed next, however this has no effect on the global `Interval`, that's already initialized and the runtime will not re-initialize it just because the global `Conf` was populated. After that `main` is executed. To fix this you can do something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/C_ySH-TMiJd. For more details see: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization.

Comment: @icza my intention is not to print the Conf.Interval. The aim is to initialise the global variable with the value read from config file multiplied by time.Second. Guess, you've overlooked the following operation, var Interval = time.Second * Conf.Interval

Comment: @dino123 Yes, overlooked that, but mkopriva already answered that the `init()` function runs after that declaration.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the explanationa and references. The suggested fix didn't work for me. pls check this link: https://play.golang.com/p/LDEeY1jQL97. Read from internet: Global and static variables go to data segment that memory is either initialized with constants you provide or by default gets initialized with zero. So global can be initialized with only constant and not on runtime with some local variable. Compiler flashes an error if global is not initialized with a constant.

Comment: @dino123 https://play.golang.com/p/OCE-2vzWDoc

Comment: @dino123 the link in your comment is no different from the original code in the question, you've only switched from `Interval` to `interval` and added a comment to the `init` function. Is there something specific you didn't understand in my previous comment? Or something about the linked specification on package initialization that is not clear to you?

Comment: @mkopriva This works fine.  I've understood now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have done the hard part: a global `Conf` object where the YAML config is unmarshaled to. So simply reference it directly:

```
// var Interval = time.Second * Conf.Interval // <- don't use this

// use Conf.Interval directly

func init() {
        PopulateConfig("./test.config")
        Conf.Interval = Conf.Interval * time.Second // convert to seconds here
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Inside main, Interval = ", Conf.Interval)
}

func Handle(ticker *time.Ticker) {
    fmt.Println("Inside Handle, Interval = ", Conf.Interval)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FiheCtV2gtv